# Why are some of my tags being removed (GWT)?

Tags: gwt

I'm adding an element to a document with the following:

```
Element parent = getParentElement(); // Returns the right thing.
HTML html = new HTML();
html.setHTML( "<td>BLAH</td>" );
parent.appendChild( html.getElement() );
```

When I view the resulting document with FireBug though, the parent's child looks like this:

`<div class="gwt-HTML"> BLAH </div>`

I can use FireBug to add in the `<td>` elements manually, and all my formatting applies, etc.  Does anyone know why the HTML element seems to be removing my `<td>` tags?

Comment: Which version of GWT are you using? IIRC, in the previous versions you had to explicitly set `asHTML` to `true` (via constructor or method). If that's not the case - try adding some simple formatting first, like `<b>` and see if that works - maybe GWT is trying to be smart and trim out the invalid HTML (`<td>` as a child of a `<div>`? Blashpemy!) And why, oh why, are you juggling around Elements instead of Widgets?

Comment: Thanks, I'm one version off current, I'll update and try asHTML.  Most formatting works elsewhere - divs, ul/li work fine.  It's just this td that I'm having trouble with.

I'm aware that the Element juggling is a special kind of pain I've brought upon myself.  In this particular project, the layout is being generated by another tool, and I need to be agnostic of it.  I'll be doing as much as I can with widgets, but I'll need to manipulate the containers they're put in as well, and I have to work directly with the Elements for that.

Comment: I think the fastest way would be firing up the debugger and stepping into that code and see at which point does the `<td>` tags get stripped - is it in the `setHTML` method, or maybe `html.getElement()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that it's FireFox that's stripping it out.  If I just use plain old javascript to create a div, or a tr, and set innerHTML to be `<td>BLAH</td>`, it still gets stripped.  A couple of others have noticed this as well: http://www.jtanium.com/2009/10/28/firefox-gotcha-innerhtml-strips-td-tags/

If I use javascript to create a `<table>` tag, and add it to the DOM, I can then place the `<td>` in that.  Of course, it helpfully creates a `<tbody><tr>` for me as well, so I'm not really getting back what I put in....

Comment: If anyone's interested, I posted a writeup of my final solution, with code, over on my blog: http://blog.grgcomponents.com/2010/08/26/firefox-is-a-thief-and-not-to-be-trusted/